# Error 405 when trying to upload text to create a file in an IIS web server folder from Objective-C on MacOS

Tags: objective-c, file-upload, http-error

I am trying to create a file from a text string in a web server folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AlekaConsulting\AlekaConsulting\License using IIS 10.0.14393.0 on a Windows Server 2016 environment using the following Objective-C code, but no file is created and  `returnString` contains the error message `405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.` No verbs are listed in the Request Filtering tab of IIS Manager, which means no verbs are blocked. webDav is not installed as a server feature. Content can be successfully read from files in the specified folder.

```
-(void) UploadFileContent: (NSString *) fileContent{
    NSString *urlString = @"https://captionpro.com.au:444/AlekaConsulting/License";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    
    // Text parameter1
    //NSString *param1 = @"parameter text";
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"parameter1\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:fileContent] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

   
    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set request body
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    //return and test
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

}

Comment: The error seems to say that it prefers a `PUT` over a `POST`?

Comment: Tried changing `[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];` to `[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];` - same error

Answer (score 0):

I have now got creation of a text file on a web server from a string working using the following code:

```
- (void) UploadFileContent: (NSString *) fileContent{

        // URL for script file on server in folder where file will be created
        NSString *urlString = @"https://xxxx/xxxx/Upload.aspx"
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
         [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
         NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
         NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

       // UploadedFile.txt is name of file to be created
       [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"UploadedFile.txt\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
      [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
      [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:fileContent] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
      [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        // set the body of the post to the request
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        // connect to the web
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

The Upload.aspx file is

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net"%>
<%@ Import NameSpace="System.Web"%>

<Script language="C#" runat=server>
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    
    foreach(string f in Request.Files.AllKeys) {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
       // FolderPath  = path to folder containing file to be created eg  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\***\***\***\
        string sFilePath = @"FolderPath" + file.FileName;
        if(System.IO.File.Exists(sFilePath)) System.IO.File.Delete(sFilePath);
        file.SaveAs(sFilePath);
    }   
}

</Script>
<html>
<body>
<p> Upload complete.  </p>
</body>
</html>
```